# How to hide ApiKey in Carto Layer request with DeckGl?

Tags: proxy, maps, deck.gl, cartodb

I am trying to hide the APIKEY in the network requests that the map is using.
I am using "@deck.gl/carto": "version": "8.6.5"

The api is set with

```
setDefaultCredentials({
  username: environment.carto_account,
  apiKey: environment.carto_api_key
});
```

The layer is being created this way:

```
new CartoLayer({
    type: MAP_TYPES.QUERY,
    pickable: true,
    id: 'countyborders',
    data: `SELECT * FROM ${CARTO.COUNTY_TABLE}`,
    getFillColor: [180,180,180,0],
    stroked: true,
    lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
    getLineColor: [ 98, 110, 120, 50 ],
  })
```

and added to the map this way:

```
<DeckGL layers={layers}>
```

then in the network to get the data we see something like:

```
https://maps-api-v2.us.carto.com/user/{profile-name}/carto/sql?source={QUERY}&format=tilejson&api_key={API_KEY}&client=deck-gl-carto
```

but we dont want to display the API_KEY to the public.

How can we keep using deckgl and carto this way and hiding this API_KEY?

I wanted to make a proxy pass through the backend, but can't seem to figure out how to use the deckgl and cartolayer pointing to a custom api not the default *maps-api-v2...*